# Calculating the Derivative of a Norm

Tags: analysis, derivatives

Let $\alpha$ be a positive real number (i.e. $\alpha > 0)$, and consider $r\left(\alpha\right) := \| Ax_{\alpha}^{\delta} - y^{\delta} \|$, where $A: X\rightarrow Y$ is a linear operator between finite-dimensional vector spaces. Now, also define $\Psi(\alpha) := \vert\vert x_{\alpha}^{\delta} \vert\vert$. In a lecture, we said that $$\frac{\mathrm dr}{\mathrm d\Psi}$$ would be negative for all $\alpha$, but I don't see this yet. I think the norm which we considered was the usual Euclidean norm, so we have $$\frac{\mathrm dr}{\mathrm d\Psi} = \frac{\mathrm d \sqrt{\|Ax_{\alpha}^{\delta}\|^2 - 2A x_{\alpha}^{\delta}y^{\delta} + \| y^{\delta} \|^2}}{\mathrm d\| x_{\alpha}^{\delta}\|}.$$

I am not quite sure how to differentiate $\|Ax_{\alpha}^{\delta}\|^2$ and $- 2A x_{\alpha}^{\delta}y^{\delta}$ with respect to $\| x_{\alpha}^{\delta} \|$.

In case is helps: **We know that $\Psi(\alpha)$ is monotone decreasing in $\alpha$.**

(I know I didn't write what $x_{\alpha}^{\delta}$ and $y^{\delta}$ are, but I believe that this is rather irrelevant for my question.)

Comment: This makes no sense. You say $\alpha$ is a ve tor, but then it appears repeatedly as A (covariant) index. And what does monotone decreasing mean for a function of a vector?

Comment: My apologies, you are right, $\alpha$ is a scalar.